# open website with drop into textbox HTML

Tags: javascript

I have made A user-script ( DOM Javascript) which included a text-box. I want the text-box to open up a google search of the input when an item is dropped. For example, if I select the word "Javascript" and drag it into the text-box, it will open up a Google search of "Javascript".

This is the code I have:

```
//only Javascript
var input2=document.createElement("input");
input2.type="text";
input2.id="Word_search";
input2.addEventListener("drop", GoogleWord);
document.body.appendChild(input2);

function GoogleWord(){
    console.log("hi");
    var text = document.getElementById("Word_search").value;
    alert(text);
    window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + text,'_blank');
}
```

(I could not use a snippet because It does not seem to work inside the snippet)

The Main problem is that the function runs before the text is inserted into the textbox, and therefore, will do a blank Google search.

So, I only need the text to be inside the text-box when the function runs.

Comment: It looks like it should work. Are you sure you didn't write `input2.addEventListener("drop", GoogleWord());`? The extra parentheses after `GoogleWord` would cause the function to be run immediately.

Comment: It works correctly for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/w0xe98fm/2/

Comment: I want it to be able to search the text that was dropped, not just open google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drop` event apparently occurs before the input is updated with the dropped text. The way to get the dropped text is with `event.dataTransfer.getData(mimetype)`.

```
function GoogleWord(event){
    console.log("hi");
    var text = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    alert(text);
    window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + text,'_blank');
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/w0xe98fm/4/)

Comment: this is exactly what i missd ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function GoogleWord(e){
   console.log("hi");
   var text =     e.target.value;
   alert(text);
   window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + text,'_blank');
}
```

Comment: What does that have to do with the problem that the function runs when the page loads instead of when he drops something into the text field?